# Are the walls slowing down minecarts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does the minecart slow down when riding between two adjacent walls? About 20% of my track is boosters, but the minecarts are still slowing down too fast. So I thought that maybe it's because of the walls? Anyone know?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your mine cart track is in a straight line, then having walls on either side should not slow it down.
If your track is running diagonally, or if it turns a corner with the walls tightly around it, then the cart may experience some "dragging"; That is, the cart will slow down as it encounters the wall.

You could try widening the tunnel where the cart goes diagonally, or where the track bends and see if that removes the problem.

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler - Ah, typo. Thanks for pointing that out. It's fixed now.

Comment: no prob. I never tried a diagonal track with adjacent walls. This sounds plausible, but is there e.g. a video to verify this?

Comment: @Tobias - I think it would be easy enough (nearly trivial) for Vlad to verify himself. I've definitely encountered the effect but I didn't see any reason to clutter up the internet with a recording of it ;-).

Answer (score 4):

If by "between two walls", you mean having walls on both sides of the track, then **no, the walls don't affect the cart's speed.** Carts lose momentum very quickly with no rider, so that may be why your carts are slowing down fast. Or perhaps your boosters aren't setup properly.

Comment: I'm riding the carts

Comment: Interesting, maybe the way your boosters are, they're accidentally boosting you then slowing you down. Either way, the walls shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I've found that there is a little bit of a dragging effect if the track runs diagonally against a wall, or turns a corner with walls around it. Try widening the walls where the track makes turns.

Comment: Ahh yes, I assumed your track was completely straight.

Comment: @Kurley: Gosh, that *answer* sounds like a good *answer* to this this question.

Comment: Ah, I'll post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a slow-down depending on the PC I'm playing on - boosters that work perfectly fine on my good machine totally fail on the slower one. Maybe this is also the case for you, try lowering the viewing distance and set the rendering to fast for comparison.